# Getting part of the @ResponseBody as an argument between backbone and a Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js

Edit: I no longer have this issue, after a redesign. Should I close this question or something?

My web portal uses backbone to construct the GUI in the browser, and Java Spring MVC on the server to serve and receive data.

In one instance, we show a list of people in the browser, that can be edited. The list is sent from the server like this in JSON:

```
[{id: 1, title: 'Städare', details: {name: 'Stefan', phone: '123456'}},
{id: 2, title: 'Sotare', details: {name: 'Arne', phone: '234567'}}]
```

The "details" section for each user contains data that can be edited, "id" is needed by backbone, and "title" is a localized field that is used for presentation only.

My issue is that I want to make a controller method like this for when the user saves changes in this data:

```
@RequestMappin(value = "/userlist/user/{id}", method = PUT)
public void saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDetails details, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    (...)
}
```

Here I want details to correspond to the "details" section in the JSON models listed above. But this doesn't work, since when I do model.save() in backbone on a model taken from the list above, it will send the big structure containing "title" and "details", which doesn't map to the UserDetails class that looks like this:

```
public class UserDetails {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
(...)
}
```

My question is: is there a way to either have my Spring MVC controller method receive the "details" part of the request body in an argument (I want it as an argument because I use the @Valid notation to run validations on the data before entering the method), or have backbone only send the details part of the model to the server. While not doing something that feels like to much of a hack.

The obvious alternative is to write a wrapper class that mimics the suberstructure around "details", and use that in the PUT controller. I would prefer not to do this partly because it's a bunch of unnecessary code, and partly because we have had problems with running validators for nested classes.

Comment: The json property `details` should bind values to the properties of `UserDetails` despite being a nested json. Make sure that you're not getting a binding error. To verify this, add a `BindingResult result` argument, to immediately follow your `details` argument, also annotate your `UserDetails` with Jackson's `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` and check your logs to see if there is something else that is causing the request to fail

Comment: Thanks for the tip about BindingResult! I must apologize however, because it was decided to redesign the forms so that I no longer have to send just part of the model in this way. I'll definitely keep this in mind, and see if I can experiment some with the old solution at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

On the backbone side it should be straight forward and easy to just send the user details section of the json. The documentation also says that you can also just send the part of model that you wish to change on the server.

Docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

So you can just send the user details for save like below:

```
model.save(
    {name: 'Stefan', phone: '123456'},
    {
     success:function(model, response, options){},
     error:function(model, response, options){}
    }
);
```

The save call in this case will attach the `idAttribute` to the `url` and send the attributes hash which in your case is user details.

Comment: If you mean the patch: true option, that won't work since while it will send only the change attributes, it will keep the hierarchy so that e.g. {id:1 {name: 'Ztefan'}} is sent. I'd only want {name: 'Ztefan'} to be sent. Since I've redesigned the solution though, I don't have the problem anymore. Wondering if I should close this question or something so no one wastes any more time on it :/